# Removing Custom UITableviewCell border

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, uitableview

I have a `tableview` in my iPhone project. Each cell of the row is customized with a separate `UITableViewCell`.

The custom cell contains an imageview and a label. My row height is 55 and hence my custom table height is also 55. Imageview lies as a background for the cell, so imageview height is also 55. But when i run the project i could see a border around each row, which seems the custom cell is having a rectangular border around its contents.

How could i be able to remove this bounding rectangle. i am working in xcode 4.2.1 and simulator 5.0.

Answer (score 2):

its possible that the border you see is the seperator, try to add this line to your code

```
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it the cell separator?

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the background view of cell-

```
cell.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
```

Comment: whether this should be after adding the new nib file?

Comment: This will be table view datasource method cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: yes in that i vae added the new code CityDetailCell *cell = (CityDetailCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CityDetailCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
         
    }

Comment: you need to add above line of code after --- cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: your table view style is plain or grouped?

Comment: You can try this as well - tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: actually it was due to the image i loaded.. it had a shadow part, which appeared as the white space.. sorry for the trouble. thank you

Comment: @krishh - you can post this as an answer,accept that and close the question.

Comment: Whats size of your background image ?

Answer (score 0):

actually it was due to the image i loaded.. it had a shadow part, which appeared as the white space.. sorry for the trouble. THANK YOU ALL